# Android how can I get an item in my xml to stay at a fixed position

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-xml

I have an XML page that has a TabLayout and RecyclerView those elements should scroll down with the page and they do, however I have a ViewPager and other TextView elements that also scroll and I do not want them too. I want those elements to stay put. For example as I scroll down the recyclerview the ViewPager should dissapear instead of scrolling down with the page. This is the code that I don't want to scroll

```
                              <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:orientation="vertical">
                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:id="@+id/TextView_TrendingArtist"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                    android:text="Trending Artists"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                                    android:id="@+id/trending_pager_list"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="200dp" />
                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                                    android:id="@+id/TextView_Artist"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                    android:text="All Artists"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                            </LinearLayout>
```

Again as I scroll down the page that LinearLayout and everything in it should not be visible. This is my full xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<data class=".ArtistListBinding">
    <variable
        name="toolbarHandler"
        type="com.mgrmobi.joox.interfaces.ToolbarClickListener" />

    <variable
        name="eventsAdapter"
        type="com.mgrmobi.joox.adapters.ArtistListAdapter" />

    <import type="android.view.View" />
</data>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_color">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@color/toolbar_color"
                    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
                    android:elevation="8dp"
                    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
                    app:elevation="8dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/menu"
                        android:layout_width="32dp"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:onClick="@{ toolbarHandler.onMenuButtonTapped }"
                        android:scaleType="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/menu" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/title"
                        style="@style/toolbarTitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/artist_list_title" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



                    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/trending_layout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
                            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                                android:background="@color/toolbar_color"
                                android:elevation="8dp"
                                android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                                app:elevation="8dp"
                                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                                app:tabIndicatorColor="#29b6f6"
                                app:tabSelectedTextColor="#FFF"
                                app:tabTextColor="#B2FFFFFF" />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_above="@+id/artist_list"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:id="@+id/TextView_TrendingArtist"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                    android:text="Trending Artists"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                                    android:id="@+id/trending_pager_list"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="200dp" />
                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                                    android:id="@+id/TextView_Artist"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                    android:text="All Artists"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                            </LinearLayout>

                            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                android:id="@+id/artist_list"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                tools:listItem="@layout/artist_card" />

                            <ProgressBar
                                android:id="@+id/paging_progress"
                                android:layout_width="48dp"
                                android:layout_height="48dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:visibility="gone" />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:text="@string/no_artists_text"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:visibility="@{ eventsAdapter.itemCount == 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE }" />
                     </LinearLayout>
                 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>



            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/progress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#82000000"
                android:gravity="center"
                tools:visibility="gone">

                <ProgressBar
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:clickable="false" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/music_controller" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_container"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#FFF" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
  </layout>
```

The issue is that the RecyclerView is also going inside the ViewPager such as this

[image]

as you can see from that image that the ViewPager partially blocks the RecyclerView once I scroll upwards .

Answer (score 0):

Using a relative layout as a parent layout of both of them may do the trick. With the relative layout, you can put a view under another. In my experience, LinearLayout always has problems putting elements with scroll.

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/trending_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        app:elevation="8dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#29b6f6"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#FFF"
        app:tabTextColor="#B2FFFFFF" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:id="@+id/artist_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/TextView_TrendingArtist"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Trending Artists"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/trending_pager_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/TextView_Artist"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="All Artists"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_below="@+id/artist_layout"
        android:id="@+id/artist_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:listItem="@layout/artist_card" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/paging_progress"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:visibility="@{ eventsAdapter.itemCount == 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE }" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Relative Layout as the main parent for the linear layouts and the content.
Here's an example for it:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollablContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footerView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerView" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```